# Is it wrong to use x instead of t in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Tags: calculus

The fundamental theorem of calculus is defined as follows: $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$$ Is it wrong to define it using x instead of t? $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(x) dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

If you had written $F(y) = \int_a^y f(x) \, dx$ it would have been okay, but as you use $x$ in two meanings - both as the upper limit of the integral and as the variable of integration - there is a problem.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you.